# Does MERGE updates when not needed?

Tags: sql-server-2012, merge

In SQL Server 2012,

Does a merge statement like this :

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
update SET A.len = B.len
```

updates a row even if A.len equals to B.len ?

Or does the SQL SERVER knows to ignore this situations ?

If not, would it be better to add the matching condition the following :

```
WHEN MATCHED AND A.len <> B.len THEN
update SET A.len = B.len
```

Is there any difference in this on other Sql servers ?

Thanks,

Comment: The short answer is yes. If you say `UPDATE column1 = column2` it will always do the update. It's not going to compare those columns unless specifically instructed to do so.

Comment: Probably the same as [The Impact of Non-Updating Updates](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx) I would guess.

Comment: I think there are [more serious things you need to worry about if you are going to use `MERGE`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)...

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is yes. You can read more about the Merge command syntax at the Microsoft [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) site.